# MATLAB function claims variable not defined

Tags: matlab

I am very new to MATLAB and trying to figure out what is going on here. I import some data from a csv file and then generate a few variables, which I then pass on to the function as follows:

```
%% Get Var[X]
VH1 = var(H1);

%% Get E[X]
EH1 = mean(H1);

%% Get s[X] (skewness)
SH1 = skewness(H1);

%% test
v = [1,1,1]
U(v)

%% function
function f = U(v)
a = v(1);
b = v(2);
c = v(3);
f = a*EH1 + b*VH1+ c*SH1;
end
```

The variables `EH1`, `VH1` and `SH1` all show up in workspace and seem to have been generated properly, but when I run the script I get:

```
Undefined function or variable 'EH1'.

Error in Inference>U (line 163)
f = a*EH1 + b*VH1+ c*SH1;

Error in Inference (line 156)
U(v);
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scoping rules for MATLAB are such that data isn't shared between the base workspace and the function workspace by default.  [To quote](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html):

> The *base workspace* stores variables that you create at the command line. This includes any variables that scripts create, assuming that you run the script from the command line or from the Editor. ...
>
> Functions do not use the base workspace. Every function has its own *function workspace*. Each function workspace is separate from the base workspace and all other workspaces to protect the integrity of the data.

`EH1`, `VH1`, and `SH1` are defined in the base workspace of the script but not the function workspace.

There are several work arounds, but I think the easiest is to just compute the moments in the function itself:

```
function f = U(v,H)
  a = v(1);
  b = v(2);
  c = v(3);
  f = a*mean(H1) + b*var(H1)+ c*skewness(H1);
end
```

or add the precomputed values to the argument list:

```
function f = U(v,EH1,VH1,SH1)
  a = v(1);
  b = v(2);
  c = v(3);
  f = a*EH1 + b*VH1+ c*SH1;
end
```

Another option is to wrap the entire code in a function, so `U` is a nested function that has access to its parent's workspace.  This is okay, but removes you data from the base workspace, which can be annoying.

The last option, which I **do not recommend** but will mention for completeness, is to explicitly link the variables between the workspaces with `global`; however, this option does not scale well for more complicated programs and should only ever be used if, for some reason, all other avenues fail with the understanding that it's not the best thing in the world and should be removed whenever possible.